# Detect external drive using simple client server socket programming in java

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I recently found a nice code to detect a external drive connected to the pc,so
I tried to experiment it with simple client server programs. 
I want server to send a notification to client whenever i connect external drive to it.

Here it the original code in java to detect a drive.

```
import java.io.*;
public class FindDrive
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
String[] letters = new String[]{ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"};
File[] drives = new File[letters.length];
boolean[] isDrive = new boolean[letters.length];

// init the file objects and the initial drive state
for ( int i = 0; i < letters.length; ++i )
    {
    drives[i] = new File(letters[i]+":/");

    isDrive[i] = drives[i].canRead();
    }

 System.out.println("FindDrive: waiting for devices...");

 // loop indefinitely
 while(true)
    {
    // check each drive 
    for ( int i = 0; i < letters.length; ++i )
        {
        boolean pluggedIn = drives[i].canRead();

        // if the state has changed output a message
        if ( pluggedIn != isDrive[i] )
            {
            if ( pluggedIn )
                System.out.println("Drive "+letters[i]+" has been plugged in");
            else
                System.out.println("Drive "+letters[i]+" has been unplugged");

            isDrive[i] = pluggedIn;
            }
        }

    // wait before looping
    try { Thread.sleep(100); }
    catch (InterruptedException e) { /* do nothing */ }

    }
}
}
```

Server Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;    
public class Pserver
{
private static Socket socket;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
    int port = 25000;
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    while(true)
    {
        //Reading the message from the client
        socket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Client has connected!");

        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
        String returnPassMessage="The device has plugged in.You can use this device";
        String returnFailMessage="The device has been unplugged";

        //detect drive code

        String[] letters = new String[]{ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J","L"};
        File[] drives = new File[letters.length];
        boolean[] isDrive = new boolean[letters.length];

    // init the file objects and the initial drive state
    for ( int i = 0; i < letters.length; ++i )
        {
        drives[i] = new File(letters[i]+":/");

        isDrive[i] = drives[i].canRead();
        }

    System.out.println("FindDrive: waiting for devices...");

     // loop indefinitely
    while(true)
        {
        // check each drive 
        for ( int i = 0; i < letters.length; ++i )
            {
            boolean pluggedIn = drives[i].canRead();

            // if the state has changed output a message
            if ( pluggedIn != isDrive[i] )
                {
                if ( pluggedIn )
                {
                    System.out.println("Drive "+letters[i]+" has been plugged in");
                    bw.write(returnPassMessage);
                }
                else
                 {   System.out.println("Drive "+letters[i]+" has been unplugged");
                    bw.write(returnFailMessage);

                isDrive[i] = pluggedIn;
                }
                }
            }

            // wait before looping
        try { Thread.sleep(2000); }
        catch (InterruptedException e) { /* do nothing */ }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Client Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Pclient
{
private static Socket socket;
public static void main(String args[])
{
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
while(true)
{
    try
    {
        String host = "localhost";
        int port = 25000;
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
        socket = new Socket(address, port);
        System.out.println("You're now connected to the Server"); 

        //Get the return message from the server
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);


        while(true)
       {
       String message = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Message received from the server : " +message);

        //to wait before loop
        try { Thread.sleep(2000); }
        catch (InterruptedException e) { /* do nothing */ }
        }


    }

    catch (ConnectException e) 
    { //When the connection is refused upon connecting to the server
       //promt the user here
    System.out.println("Connection refused");
    break;
    }
    catch (IOException exception)
    {
        //when connection drops, server closed, loses connection
     //promt the user here
    System.out.println("Disconnected from server");
    break; //to quit the infinite loop
    }
}
}
}
```

The standalone detect drive code works perfectly. but whenever it runs on server the *"drive has been plugged in"* message repeats and most importantly no message is sent to client. please help!

Comment: ahh, I just had to flush bufferedwriter bw and add "/n" at the end of message. Now the client receives message. Even though it serves the purpose, there are still bugs.